# Mail Template gradient

Tags: html-table, html-email, gradient

I want a gradient shadow along the side of the content row. The gradient must expand in relation to the content.
What I'm doing right now is having 9 td's with a right border next to my content. This works in Thunderbird, but not Outlook:

```
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #cbcbcb;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #c9c9c9;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #c6c6c6;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #bdbdbd;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #b6b6b6;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #afafaf;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;"></td>
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #9e9e9e;"></td>
```

I get a nice gradient shadow in Thunderbird, but in Outlook I get the left-border as a white line. I have also tried to to make the td's like: this:

```
<td style="width: 1; bgcolor: #cbcbcb"></td>
```

This works in outlook, but Thunderbird does not seems to render a td at all that has no content.

Last I tried to make a left and right border like this:

```
<td style="border: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border-right: 1px solid #cbcbcb; left-border: #c9c9c9;"></td>
```

This worked in Thunderbird but not in Outlook.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you have screenshots and/or a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: @samanthasquared Here is how it looks in outlook: http://bildr.no/image/1296566.jpeg when I use borders. Why do you want to see a screenshot of my code? I have pasted it in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your issue, but posting your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ or something similar is extremely helpful. All you posted was 9 table cells, from this I don't know if you have malformed tables or any number of other issues that could be happening with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using a transparent 1x1px gif like this:

```
<td rowspan="6" width="1" bgcolor="#9e9e9e"><img src="http://www.blabla.com/new_mail_template/spacer.gif"></td>
```

Thunderbird does not show empty cells so I had to put something into them